# Store secret key securely in .NET Standard cross-platform app

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, cross-platform, securestring

I'm working on a C# PowerShell module, which is going to be a simple wrapper around some service REST API. I'd like to target PowerShell Standard / .NET Standard and make module available across all supported platforms.

For this app authentication requires API token, issued on a service website by the user. Entering key every time you open a session would be extremely inconvenient and therefore I need some way to securely store the API key in a user profile.

The problem is - I cannot find an easy way to encrypt data that has transparent cross-platform support. Initially, I wanted to use `SecureString`, but it is (a) [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netcore-3.1) and (b) doesn't seem to have good support on Linux. In a perfect world I'd like to have some mechanism similar to Windows encryption - user certificate encrypts API key and I put result in a text file in a user folder.

This is not a financial or mission-critical application, top-notch security is not required, but still keening plain text secrets in my home folder makes me nervous. Yes, I'm talking to you, AWS SDK authors :)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was: "just save secret key to ENV variables..."
But if I understood OP's question correctly, it is required to restrict unauthorized reading of this secret even on OP's machine.

One option I could see is just create a folder (or maybe file) and give it the access permissions only for one particular user. Ultimately one can create new user account which will be used to run the code in powershell and give this new user exclusive permissions to read secret file. This will prevent some 3rd party programs running from OP's account to read secret file.

Comment: Yes, I think home folders should have default permission for current user only, but I have no control over this as a module author. Many giant industry providers (did I mention AWS? :) ) rely on this and just keep plain text secrets in the home folder. Maybe there is no other way and I'm a little paranoid.

Comment: As module author you can create sub folder inside home folder. Also you can provide instructions for ~paranoid~... I mean for users who cares about security a lot to change permissions for your data folder.

Comment: As for AWS and other cloud providers, they threat the host machine as your own secure fortress where only you can read Environment vars or read private file system folders. So they don't see anything wrong in plain text secrets in home folder.
PS: just in case... avoid committing secrets into the Git repo.